# Named Virtual Hosts Apache2 and 301 Redirect from root domain to a subdomain

Tags: redirect, apache-2.2

I know that this question comes up often, I followed many examples and suggestions, but i just cant get it to work. Heres what I need to achieve:

I have two configure two domains to redirect to subdomain of one of them: 
domain-one.com (and www.domain-one.com) and domain-two.com should all send 301 Moved Permamently header and redirect to www.domain-two.com.

I've set up NamedVirtualHost for domain-one.com as follows:

```
ServerName domain-one.com
ServerAlias www.domain-one.com
Redirect 301 ^/ http://www.domain-two.com
```

And that seems to work for domain-one.com but www.domain-one.com does not redirect, whole setup seems to be ignored and files from server's default host configuration setup are served.

As for redirecting from domain-two.com to www.domain-two.com I created two NamedVirtualHosts, www.domain-two.com is the actual site with its configuration (ServerName set to www.domain-two.com) and domain-one.com is configured with this:

```
ServerName domain-two.com 
Redirect 301 ^/ http://www.domain-two.com
```

And this configuration also fails.

From what I read about redirecting within Apache Redirect directive should be sufficient to achieve what I need. I could use some mod_rewriting or even use PHP and appropriated headers() to do what I want, but can someone please explain to me what is wrong with my thinking and this configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Redirect permanent /(.*) http://www.domain-two.com/$1
```

Incase you don't want to append the request to the domain then you can do

```
Redirect permanent /(.*) http://www.domain-two.com
```